# edmx connection string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, connection-string, edmx

I am developing an application that uses edmx for dataaccess.
I realized that each edmx file have its own connection string in the configuration file.
Is there a way to share one connection string for all the edmx files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No - there isn't.**

And for good reason. The connection string in Entity Framework contains much more than regular connection strings (e.g data source / database name).

It contains crucial information about the different components of the model, including the CSDL, which is **unique to the model**.

Perhaps you could explain if you are planning to share a connection string between different EDMX's, then why do you need seperate EDMX's in the first place?

If your looking at a way to dynamically create a connection string then look at **EntityConnectionStringBuilder.**

Comment: It makes sense to use separate EDMXes if your database is large enough that you need to partition your tables up. An EDMX cannot reasonably handle over 150 tables. I couldn't even get it to respresent our entire database - we have it partitioned up into ~20 different EDMXes. That said, I totally understand the reasons for not sharing the connection strings (CSDL, SSDL, MSL). I just wanted to point out the issues with very large databases.